# CMIS Workbench properties editor shows 3 cmis:name

Tags: alfresco, cmis, cmis-workbench

I want to edit the `cmis:name` of a document in CMIS Workbench, so I selected the document, opened its Properties tab (left window in the screenshot below), and double-clicked on `cmis:name`.

The Property Editor showed up (right window in the screenshot below), and surprisingly to me it contains 3 rows for the field `cmis:name`:

[image]

What is the difference between each of the three?

*(remark: as you can see, the same happens for `cmis:description`)*

Comment: How many versions does your node have ? (Just an idea)

Comment: @Akah: Just one version (1.0) it seems, as Alfresco Share shows "This document has no previous versions".

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Alfresco.

I reported it at https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-21974

The issue is currently marked as "In progress".